# Incorporate egrep regexps with awk?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I've been trying to understand how `awk` can work with `egrep` regular expressions.
I have the following example:

```
John,Milanos    
Anne,Silverwood    
Tina,Fastman    
Adrian,Thomassonn
```

I'm looking to use egrep regexps to process the second column (the last names in this scenario)  while printing the entire line for output.

The closest I've come to my answer was using?

```
$ awk -F ',' '{print $2}' | egrep '([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2'
Thomassonn
```

I would then take "Thomassonn" and egrep back into my initial list of full names to get the full record. However, I've encountered plenty of errors and false positives once I used other filters.

Desired result:

```
Adrian,Thommasson
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` does not support back-references within a regex.  `egrep`, however, is sufficient to achieve your desired result:

```
$ egrep ',.*([a-z])\1.*([a-z])\2' file
Adrian,Thomassonn
```

#### Variations

If there are three or more columns and you want to search only the second:

```
egrep '^[^,]*,[^,]*([a-z])\1[^,]*([a-z])\2' file
```

If you want to search the third column:

```
egrep '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*([a-z])\1[^,]*([a-z])\2' file
```

If you want to search the first of any number of columns:

```
egrep '^[^,]*([a-z])\1[^,]*([a-z])\2' file
```

Comment: Thanks John. How will I be able to switch this to column 1 ? or an additional column 3 for that matter ?

Answer (score 0):

awk doesn't support backreferences, here's one way to do what you want instead:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="," }
{
    numMatches = 0
    fld = $2
    for (charNr=1; charNr <= length($2); charNr++) {
        char = substr($2,charNr,1)
        if (char ~ /[a-z]/)
            numMatches += gsub(char"{2}"," ",fld)
    }
}
numMatches >= 2
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Adrian,Thomassonn
```

If you want to match sequences of 3 or any other number of repeated chars, just change `{2}` to `{3}` or whatever number you like.

By the way, for portability to all locales you should use `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[a-z]` if that's what you really mean.